# Procedimientos almacenados C# y SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Buen día estoy realizando una conexión a SQL SERVER para procedimientos almacenados estoy realizando el de búsqueda pero por nombre pero me me ejecuta ya que me sale un error en esta linea (nombre = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()); que dice  no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo int en string entonces no ogro saber como hacerlo.
mi codigo es el siguiente.`introducir el código aquí`

```
public static string BuscarUsuario(string usuario)
    {
        string nombre;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(TraerCandena("AppUsuariosAsus.Properties.Settings.pruebaConnectionString")))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "Buscar_Usuario";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombres", usuario);

                nombre = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return (nombre);
    }
```

EN SQL ES ASI 
create procedure BuscarUsuario
@nombres varchar(100)
as
select nombres
from USUARIO
where nombres = @nombres

Comment: si el procesure realiza un select porque usas el ExecuteNonQuery() ? eso no es correcto deberias usar un reader o un datatable para obtener la respuesta, o si es un valor simple el ExecuteScalar()

Comment: En la linea
nombre = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); aun me siga botando error pero que dice que no se puede convertir  el tipo 'object' en string que ay existe una conversión explicita y los otros 2 que nombras no los e usado no se como usarlos.

Comment: si analizas la respuesta, veras que aplico cun Convert.ToString() al ExecuteScalar() para obtener el string que se recupera

Comment: Asegúrate que tu query con el argumento usado sólo trae un registro. ejecútalo por fuera (sql management studio) y verifica. también puedes poner un select top 1 ... en tu query.

Answer (score 3):

Usa el `ExecuteScalar()` para obtener el valor de la columna

```
public static string BuscarUsuario(string usuario)
{
    string nombre;

    string connstring = TraerCandena("AppUsuariosAsus.Properties.Settings.pruebaConnectionString");
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Buscar_Usuario", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombres", usuario);

            nombre = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }

    return nombre;
}
```